# turn several line function into a one liner list format

Tags: python, list

I am learning and I am trying to make this code nicer and learn more in pythonic way! I wanna turn this code into a one line code inside list (list comprehension). e.g., [here goes the new implementation]

```
def main():
    inp = input()
    x = []
    x_tm = ''
    for i in range( 0, len(inp)):
        if inp[i] == ',':
            x.append(x_tm)
            x_tm = ""
            continue
        if inp[i] ==" ":
            continue
        x_tm += inp[i]
    x.append(inp)
```

Comment: Do you mean a list comprehension?

Comment: It's hard to understand your goal.  What's your `input()` supposed to be like?  You could provide some sample inputs and outputs to make your question easier to follow.

Comment: Don't use `for i in range(0, len(inp)):`. Use `for c in inp:`

Comment: If the code works and you're looking for advice on improving it, [codereview.se] is the appropriate place. But see https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users first.

Comment: @Barmar yes exactly looking for list comprehension

Comment: OP *probably* want `x = [n.strip() for n in inp.split(',')]`  but this code doesn't produce that result correctly.  The last line should be `x.append(x_tm)`.

Answer (score 1):

There is a built-in function called "split" that does what you wrote.

```
def main():
inp = input("Enter text: ").split(",")
print(inp)
```

If you want to write the function yourself it would look something like this:

```
def main():
inp = input("Enter text: ")
temp = ""
words = []
for ltr in inp:
    if ltr == ",":
        words.append(temp)
        temp = ""
    else:
        temp += ltr
if len(temp):
    words.append(temp)
print(words)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function reads a line, then computes something from it without printing, returning, or any other kind of "output". Hence here's an equivalent one liner:

```
main = input
```